# How to remove a column with NA value from flextable in R

Tags: r, flextable

I created a data frame containing full year and year to date summaries. Since the current year , say 2022, has no full year data, so it would be NA in the pivot table under the 2022 column.

However using `flextable` through `tabulator`, 2022 will still show up in the output such as below.

```
ct <- tabulator(
  x = test, rows = c("Sex", "Measure", "AgeGroup"),
  columns = "timer",
  `2019` = as_paragraph(as_chunk(Yr2019, formatter = as.integer)), 
  `2020` = as_paragraph(as_chunk(Yr2020, formatter = as.integer)),
  `2021` = as_paragraph(as_chunk(Yr2021, formatter = as.integer)),
  `2022` = as_paragraph(as_chunk(Yr2022, formatter = as.integer))
)
ft <- as_flextable(ct)
ft
```

How can I remove the 2022 column under full year?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I found a solution, which is just to delete the attribute column inside `ct$visible_columns`

`ct$visible_columns <- ct$visible_columns[-8, ]`

or

`ct$visible_columns <- ct$visible_columns[ct$visible_columns$col_keys != "@Full year@2022",]`.

Then the output would appear as

[image]